# Conditional shell usage in google colab

Tags: shell, conditional-statements, google-colaboratory

I work with Google Colab & Drive
I want to download data to my drive directory only if it was not previously downloaded.
something like this :

```
if not os.path.isdir('dir'):
    !wget data
```

but ! is not recognized when indented..
Is there a way to write conditional code using shell?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

In shell scripting the "if" condition is usually written like this:

```
if [ os.path.isdir != "dir" ] ; then
    !wget data
fi
```

Maybe that is the reason why it's not working. Let me know if I got the question right!

By the way: is os.path.isdir a variable? Some additional details would be helpful to better understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried this way, it does not work..
Which additional details?

Comment: For it to work, lines 1 and 3 need to start with `!` too. (haven't tested it tho)